# checking if session variable is null returns nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, session

I have a List of objects stored in a session variable.  But when I check to make sure the session variable is not null, it gives me a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
if(Session["object"] == null)  //error occurs here
{
     Session["object"] = GetObject();
     return Session["object"] as List<object>;
}
else
{
    return Session["object"] as List<object>;
}
```

How can I check if the Session is null?

edit:  I also tried

```
if(Session["object"] != null)
```

Comment: Have you checked that `Session` is not null?

Comment: Are you sure that your error occurs within in the line with your if-condition?

Comment: Which object is `null`?  Based on the description, it sounds like `Session` itself is `null`, which would mean that there *is* no `Session` in this context.

Comment: Where you have this code ? is it in a code behind of web page ? or is it part of web service ? ??

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the IF ad look at the session contents. If its null and you dont expect it to be, then debug from there.

Comment: I wonder if there's a problem with the fact that the session variable is named "object".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> edit: I also tried
>
> ```
> if(Session["object"] != null)
> ```

Note that the code in your edit is **not** checking that `Session` is not null. If it is null, the expression `Session["object"]` will still cause the error because this is searching the session instance for the "object" key - so if you think about it logically you are looking for a key in an uninstantiated object, hence the null reference exception. Therefore you need to verify `Session` has been instantiated before checking if `Session["object"]` is null:

```
if (Session != null)
{
    if(Session["object"] == null)
    {
         Session["object"] = GetObject();
         return Session["object"] as List<object>;
    }
    else
    {
        return Session["object"] as List<object>;
    }
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully we will see monadic null checking implemented in C# 6.0 to simplify this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if `Session != null`? In your example, both `this.Session` and `this.Session["Key"]` can return `null`, but you checked only the latter. Take into account the option that the `Session` itself might not exist, so you cannot get data from it, but also cannot write to it.

Comment: @Mike: Define "I have" and "didn't seem to work."  According to your description, `Session` itself appears to be `null`.  What did you try?  How did it not work?  What are you attempting to accomplish here?

Comment: by the way this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Checking if Session is null is at least part of the solution. I have had this same problem. Session can be null depending on config/settings of your system, or if you're deep inside some module that doesn't support Session, yet the namespace is still available.

Answer (score 0):

have you check your GetObject() method...it may return null...

Answer (score 0):

Try checking `if (!Session.ContainsKey("object"))` after checking `if (Session != null)`. If those checks both pass, then `Session["object"]` should be fine.